# complete irreducibility of projection representation

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, and $F$ be a field. $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $F$. Then a group homomorphism $\rho: G \rightarrow PGL(V)$ is called a projection representation of $G$. For projection representations:

1. define the concepts of subrepresentation and irreducibility;
2. state and prove [Maschke's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem) for complete reducibility in this case.

There is a brief proof for Maschke's theorem. Let $\rho: G \rightarrow GL(V)$ be a representation of $G$. If $V'$ is a subspace of $V$ stable under $\rho(G)$, we can set $V = V' \oplus W'$ where $W'$ is another subspace of $V$. Let $\pi: V \rightarrow V'$ be the corresponding projection. Define $$\psi: V \rightarrow V', v \mapsto \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} g^{-1}\pi(gv),$$ then we can prove that the the restriction of $\psi$ on $V'$ is the identity map, and the kernel of $\psi$ is the complement of $V'$, which is also stable under $\rho(G)$. This defines an decomposition of $\rho: G \rightarrow GL(V)$.

**MY PROBLEM**: I think a subrepresentation for $\rho: G \rightarrow PGL(V)$ is $\rho: G \rightarrow PGL(V')$ where $V'/F^*$ is a subspace of $V/F^*$ stable under the action of $\rho(G)$. Am I right? As to irreducibility, I think this is "Let $G$ be a finite group, and $F$ be a field. Then any projection representation $\rho: G \rightarrow PGL(V)$ is completely reducible for any finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over $F$." The requirement that $|G|$ is not divisible by the characteristic of $F$ can be dropped because the term $\frac{1}{|G|}$ can be dropped in defining $\psi$. I am not sure if I am right.

Thanks very much.

Comment: I am looking for a good treatment of projective representations (one that handles all of the standard ordinary representation issues with them). This exercise sounds like the kind of thing I want addressed. What book or notes is it from?